# iso9660 filesystem when remade with a slight change blows its size by 100M

Tags: linux, filesystems, iso-image

I have an iso 9660 filesystem image in which I need to edit just one file. I copied the files using `cp -avf`. When the files reach the destination, the sizes increase. That must be due to the increase in block size.

But when I remake the iso9660 filesystem using `mkisofs -J -U -r` the sizes of the files remain the same and just a small editing in a file leads to a blow up of about 100M in the newly created iso image. I think I'm missing some option there, but I'm not able to find out in the manpage and google search. Some quick help would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck.

My host filesystem is ext3..if that's required.

Comment: The original ISO9660 image may have been written in a "transparent compression" mode, which compresses the data being written.  This could explain your ~100M difference.  See the -z flag in the mkisofs man page, also the mkztree man page.  Also, the -U flag is not recommended, as it breaks many standards.  Your resultant CD may not be readable on all systems.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'd'nt been online for quite some time.Thanks. I used it and got a perfect working copy of my filesystem. Even the -z flag isn't recommended outside linux. I used the -U flag to enable various features which are unique to Unix but violates iso9660 standards.Please point out if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Did the -z flag fix things for you?

Comment: Yeah it did because I used the resulting image in a Linux system. There's a line in the man page after the '-z' option ---"The resulting disks are only transparently readable if used on Linux.". That's why I said the "-z not recommended" part. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The original ISO9660 image may have been written in a "transparent compression" mode, which compresses the data being written. This could explain your ~100M difference. See the **-z** flag in the *mkisofs* man page, also the *mkztree* man page. Also, the **-U** flag is not recommended, as it breaks many standards. Your resultant CD may not be readable on all systems.